# Correct way to set up Marionette Js with core AMD build?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, marionette

I am learning Marionett on the side, and am trying to stick to the core amd build and not shim marionett. here's my require config:

```
require.config({
  paths : {
    backbone : 'lib/backbone',
    underscore : 'lib/underscore',
    jquery : 'lib/jquery',
    marionette : 'lib/backbone.marionette',
    'backbone.wreqr' : 'lib/backbone.wreqr',
    'backbone.babysitter' : 'lib/backbone.babysitter',
    hbs : 'lib/hbs',
    Handlebars : 'lib/Handlebars'
  },
  shim : {
    jquery : {
      exports : 'jQuery'
    },
    underscore : {
      exports : '_'
    },
    backbone : {
      deps : ['jquery', 'underscore'],
      exports : 'Backbone'
    }
  },

  hbs: {
    disableI18n: true,

    disableHelpers: true

  }
});
```

I am getting Backbone is undefined in the application module of marionette when I create an application module as follows:

```
define(["marionette", "views/CatCompositeView"], function (Marionette, CatCompositeView) {

  var app = new Marionette.Application();

  app.addRegions({
    mainRegion: '#content'
  });

  app.addInitializer(function(options){
    var catCompositeView = new CatCompositeView({
      collection: options.cats
    });

    app.mainRegion.show(catCompositeView);

  });

  return app;
});
```

Any ideas?  I am able to get it all working when shimming marionette so I'm ok for now, but would like to load it all individually.

UPDATE:  Here's how I ended up doing this in my require config:

```
require.config({
  paths : {
    backbone : 'lib/backbone',
    underscore : 'lib/underscore',
    jquery : 'lib/jquery',
    marionette : 'lib/backbone.marionette',
    'backbone.wreqr' : 'lib/backbone.wreqr',
    'backbone.babysitter' : 'lib/backbone.babysitter',
    hbs : 'lib/hbs',
    Handlebars : 'lib/Handlebars'
  },
  shim : {
    jquery : {
      exports : 'jQuery'
    },
    underscore : {
      exports : '_'
    },
    backbone : {
      deps : ['jquery', 'underscore'],
      exports : 'Backbone'
    },
    'backbone.wreqr': {
      deps : ['backbone']
    },
    'backbone.babysitter': {
      deps : ['backbone']
    }
  },

  hbs: {
    disableI18n: true,

    disableHelpers: true

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to shim `Backbone.Marionnette` too:

```
marionette : {
  deps: ["backbone", "underscore"],
  exports: "Backbone.Marionette"
}
```

Comment: I have it working with the shim way of doing it, however, in  https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/Using-marionette-with-requirejs  under andvanced usage it seems to indicate that you don't have to do it that way.

Comment: @simon : right, that's the way to do it but the dependencies for marionette are backbone, wreqr, and babysitter, as long as underscore is direct dependency of backbone

Comment: @Kelly : "you don't have to do it that way"...  but it works!

Answer (score 0):

See update above. I needed to add backbone as a dependency for wreqr and babysitter to load them individually.